# information on hover and multiple feature selection

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm working with OpenLayer 3.1.1, starting from this example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/examples/vector-layer.html?q=hover
I would like show information on mouse hover and select multiple feature on click. Going to add the second feature to the selection it is selected twice. Why?

```
  var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click, 
  addCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly ,
  toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never,
  removeCondition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
  });   

  select = selectClick;
  map.addInteraction(select);

var highlightStyleCache = {};
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
map: map,
style: function(feature, resolution) {
var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('DIVISION') : '';
if (!highlightStyleCache[text]) {
  highlightStyleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#f00',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
      text: text,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#000'
      }),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#f00',
        width: 1
      })
    })
  })];
}
return highlightStyleCache[text];
}
});

var highlight;
var showCheckbox = document.getElementById('infoShow'); 

var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;         
    });

    if (showCheckbox.checked) { 
        if (feature) {
            if (feature.getKeys()=='geometry,COORDINATOR COUNTRY') {
            infoBox.innerHTML = '<strong>Coordinator Country: </strong>' + feature.get('COORDINATOR COUNTRY')+ '<br>'+ '<br>';  
            } 
            else {
                infoBox.innerHTML = '<strong>Area: </strong>' + feature.get('AREA') + '<br>'+'<strong>Marine division: </strong>' + feature.get('DIVISION');
            }   
            } else {
            infoBox.innerHTML = '&nbsp;'+'<br>'+ '<br>';
        }  
    if (feature !== highlight) {            
        if (highlight) {
        featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);                
        }
        if (feature) {
        featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);             
        }
        highlight = feature;                
        } 
    }       
    };

    $(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);   
    displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it is selected twice"?

Comment: the second (and following) feature becomes darker than the first selected one and keeping track of the features currently selected this is counted twice.   `map.on('click',function(){  
 setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("selInfo");
  var txt = [];
  var obj = select.getFeatures()
  if (obj){
  for (var i = 0, ii = obj["a"].length; i < ii; ++i){   
   txt.push(obj["a"][i]["o"]["DIVISION"]);       
  }     
  infoBox2.innerHTML = txt.length ? ('<strong>Selected Marine Divisions: </strong>'+ txt.join(', ')) : '&nbsp;'; 
  infoBox3.innerHTML = txt.length;    
  }
  },50)
 });`

Comment: It's still difficult to understand what you mean. Could you describe the expected/actual output, or produce a reproducible example? The code you added uses private attributes. You should use the API attributes and methods, both for readability and stability. Use `select.getFeatures().forEach(function(feature){ txt.push(feature.get("DIVISION ")); });`.

Comment: I started from the example above to create the feature overlay for the highlight and getting the DIVISION info.It works.I added a select interactiont but on-click features (add condition) are selected twice. I think it happens because of the Feature overlay that is created when the user hovers over. Is it possible?how to filter out the featureOverlay?or something like disabling the on.click event when the feature overlay exists?

Comment: I made this attempt inside the `var displayFeatureInfo` definition:                                                            `setTimeout(function(){
 featureOverlay.getFeatures().clear();
  },500)`                                                                                                      working better....but not fluid.